# Modal Dialog Delegate Event not firing

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog that I call from my sender page:

```
function openCommentsDialog( ITEMID)
{
    var DropDownListValue = document.getElementById("HideVal").value;
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = "/_layouts/SRP/SRPChange2.aspx" + "?Type=" + DropDownListValue    + "&ItemID=" + ITEMID;        //"SRPChange.aspx" + "?Type=" + DropDownListValue +"&ItemID=" + ITEMID;
    options.height = 600;
    options.width = 800;
    options.allowMaximize = false;

    options.Title = "SRP Change Dialog";
    **options.dialogReturnValueCallBack = Function.createDelegate(null,  dialogCloseCallBack);**
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

}
```

This is the callback function on the sender page:

```
function dialogCloseCallBack(result, returnValue) {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(result);
}
```

On the dialog page I have dynamically added a "Close" button. I have tried client script and server script but the `diaglogCloseCallBack` function on the sender page never fires:

**Client**:

```
function closeWindow() {    
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Close,null);
}
```

**Server**:

```
private void Close_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(0,null);</script>");
    this.Context.Response.Flush();
    this.Context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Why have you added a close button dynamically? Won't the options.showClose = true work?

Comment: When I do that the Close button doesn't show up.

Comment: Even when I click the "X" to close the window, the delegate event doesn't fire.

Comment: Can you try changing your function to:
 function dialogCloseCallBack(result, returnValue) {

         alert(result);
 }
and then clicking on the "x" to close.

Comment: The dialogCloseCallBack function doesn't fire.  That is the problem.